# Custom urls and paths in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models: `Books` and `pages` in a typical one_to_many relationship.

How can I make the following

```
page_path(@page)
```

output this path:

```
bookname/page/pageid
```

instead of

```
page/pageid
```

If I override the to_param, all I can do is make a path like `localhost/page/bookid/pageid` but that's not what I want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I globally override a rails url helper?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675193/how-can-i-globally-override-a-rails-url-helper)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that to have full control over path helpers, you have to override those inside the `application_helper.erb` file. The following code worked for me:

```
def pages_path(@page)
  @bookpath = Book.find(@page.book_id)
  @bookpath + '/page/' + @page.id
end
```

The helper only creates the path. You still need to link it to a particular action in `routes.rb`. You may even nest the `pages` resource inside the `books` resource. The only important thing is that the path generated by the above helper must be recognizable by the rails application.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's possible to get exactly what you want, but you can make the Page a nested resource under book like this:

```
resources :books do
  resources :pages
end
```

Then you will get:

`localhost/book/bookid/page/pageid`

Then you can override `to_param' to get:

`localhost/book/bookid-bookname/page/pageid`

Comment: if I do nesting, I'll have to use helpers like `books_pages_path(@book,@page)`. I need to use the plain `pages_path(@page)` helper.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean to have path as /:book_name/page/:id

In routes.rb:

```
match '/:book_name/page/:id' => "page#show", :as => :page
```

In the controller you would access params[:id] to get page.id and params[:book_name] to get the name of the book.

Comment: Routing is working pretty well. I'm exactly stuck over not being able to use the page_path helper to output this exact path.

Comment: no. with this definition in the routes.rb you'll have to provide book name as an argument to the page_path function like `page_path("Some Book Name",@page)`